# Jquery Uncaught Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, typeerror

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <!--loading bootstrap js-->

 <!--CORE JAVASCRIPT-->
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         setupResponsiveTables();
     });

     function setupResponsiveTables() {
         $(".responsiveTable1").responsiveTable({
             staticColumns: 0,
         });
         $(".overflowContainer").scrollLeft(0);
     }
 </script>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: setupResponsiveTables is not defined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).responsiveTable is not a function

Kindly help me i cant find any fix :S

Comment: `responsiveTable` is not a standard jQuery method, and you don't appear to have included it in any referenced script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reference to the responsive table plugin.
add responsive query plugin;

```
<script src="js/jquery.responsivetable.min.js"></script>
```

You can get the plugin from http://declanbright.awardspace.info/jquery-plugin-responsive-table if not already downloaded.